# Snowflake uses where-clause in wrong place when joining

Tags: sql, join, view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause

I have views that I need to join, and these have filters to exclude records with invalid data. In the views the filtering is done before the remaing records are cast to their respecive data type, but when joining the views it is not. The join fails on invalid records even though the views standalone do not deliver them.

Here is a very simplified example:

```
create or replace table SRC (DTM varchar);
insert into SRC values ('2020-01-01'),('00-00-00');

create or replace view SRC_V as 
(
    select DTM::timestamp as DTM 
    from SRC where DTM!='00-00-00'
);

select * from
SRC_V as a 
inner join SRC_V as b
ON a.DTM = b.DTM;
```

This gives `Timestamp '00-00-00' is not recognized` so even though the view filters this record out, it is still present in the join.

Unfortunately I can not manipulate the views, and the join code is generated by a code generator so there is not a lot of options to make special code for just this scenario, so I need to understand if this is a bug or by design before we make any major changes to accommodate for this.

I have tried this case in SQL Server where it works as I expect.

Also, there are variants that do work, such as:

```
with x as (select DTM from SRC_V)
select * from
x as a 
inner join x as b
ON a.DTM = b.DTM;
```

If the behaviour is by design, I feel that this example should also fail. It also works with `full outer` but not with `left` or `right` outer which also feels strange.

Comment: Why do you store timestamps in a varchar column?

Comment: The original data comes from text-files, and the conversion must be made somewhere.

Comment: Can't you do the conversion while inserting? Proper data types, and valid data, would make things easier.

Comment: Yes of corce, but as I said the views are not ours and will not be changed. Also it is more a question about how Snowflakes optimizer handles this scenario and if this is something we need to accomodate for in the code generation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. Because you're performing a self-join (join on the same table), the optimizer knows that it can apply the where clause predicate on both scans. Notice the plan has the filter for `!='00-00-00'` twice, once in Filter2 and once in Filter4:

[image]

Applying a where clause predicate on a scan can reduce (prune) the number of micropartitions Snowflake has to scan. Pruning by where clause happens before execution starts and is usually more effective at pruning than the next operator up the plan, which is JoinFilter [5].

As far as why this does not happen with a CTE, it's a completely different plan. By the time the join happens the rows are already scanned and passed through the filter:

[image]

However, using a CTE is not a guarantee that it will always work this way. The Snowflake optimizer can and will change plans based on the warehouse size and data volumes. It's possible that while this plan works at small scale, running it with much higher row counts could form a plan that encounters the same filtering problem as the view.

You mentioned that something is generating the code and that you may not have access to it, but the safest way to handle this situation is to change how the view is casting the varchar to a timestamp. Use of the `::` notation for casting does not handle errors. You can have someone who can change the code and/or views to use something that will handle errors, something like this:

```
create or replace view SRC_V as 
(
    select try_to_timestamp(DTM) as DTM 
    from SRC where DTM!='00-00-00'
);
```

This will convert the 00-00-00 values to database `null`, and because null does not equal anything including database null, it will not join these rows.

Edit: I would also be careful about aliasing computed columns to the same names as an existing column in the table, particularly when joining on that column. While it works in this simple example, it could present problems. Here's a KB article discussing it:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Beware-with-Column-Aliases-in-Joins

It will be safer to change the alias to a different name than the original column and use that alias in the join condition.

Comment: Thanks! However I still have some problems with this, partly because it does not need to be a self join (this was my first suspicion) but also as the execution plan says, Filter2 andFilter4 are aplied before the join

Comment: It does not need to be a self join. Using a predicate in a where clause prunes better than a join filter, and the optimizer may do that. As far as Filter2 and Filter4 being applied before the join, the problem is that the error is happening during that filter. In general it's never safe to use an expression that can lead to an error. For example, something like `iff(my_column = 5, 1/0, 1)` should never need to evaluate the second parameter if no values in my_column equal 5, but an optimizer is free to evaluate expressions any way it wants to do so for performance reasons.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the only correct way is to change the views (to use "try" to get nulls is clever that hadn't occurred to me) and that is the path we need to look at. and that the optimizer reorganize the SQL is of course fine, but I always interpreted the execution plan as a more or less a step by step map on how optimizer had decided to actually solve the problem, hence my confusion with the filter before the join. But if I understand you correctl this is maybe a far to simplistic way of interpreting executionplans?

Comment: I think you're understanding the plan. The key thing to know is that the Snowflake's optimizer is always free to rearrange operations if it thinks the plan will run better. A CTE is usually the most likely way a SQL writer can signal the optimizer to perform operations in a particular order, but the optimizer can and does sometimes pull apart the structure of a CTE and perform operations in a an order that does not reflect how its flow's order is written in the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The shorter answer than Greg’s is Snowflake for performance reason violated standard ordering of operations.

Aka

```
Select column1::date
From table_name
Where clause that only allows date values
```

In the above, sql rule say the WHERE should run before the SELECT, but in snowflake the optimizer can and does (and as Greg notes it can change the logic dynamically) put the cast on the data before applying the filter. So if there is data that fails the cast, that would be filtered out by the filter, you can get errors. This mostly happens for stings or variants.

To work around this you need to use the `try_` versions of the casts. Once you get over the grumbling and learn to play along. It just becomes simple again.